# Visual Basic Grade generator

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

For my project we are supposed to create a grade calculator. So far I have everything working. All the averages and final grade are calculated. What I am having trouble with is: how do I convert the numerical grade to an alphabetical grade.

This is the code for getting the final grade calculated.

```
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim result1 As Integer
        Dim result2 As Integer
        Dim result3 As Integer
        Dim attendance As Integer
        Dim project As Integer
        Dim result As Decimal

        result1 = Val(totalResultLabel.Text)
        result2 = Val(totalResultLabel.Text)
        result3 = Val(totalResultLabel.Text)
        attendance = Val(attendanceTextBox.Text)
        project = Val(projectTextBox.Text)

        result = (result1 * 0.3) + (result2 * 0.15) + (result3 * 0.2) + _
                 (attendance * 0.1) + (project * 0.25)

        finalResultLabel.Text = result
    End Sub
```

With the end result I would want: if a student received an 85, the visual should say a B. I know I have to add images but would I add a button to for the conversion? I am just very confused.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to do something like:

```
    ....
    result = (result1 * .....
    Dim strResult as String

    Select Case result
        Case 0 To 10
            strResult = "F"
        Case y To z
            strResult = x
    End Select
    finalResultLabel.Text = strResult
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, declare an array for the grades (A, B, C, etc) and their minimum points for each grade.

E.g:

```
Dim GradeTable = New Dictionary(Of String, Decimal) From {{"A", 90D}, {"B", 80D}, {"C", 70D}, {"D", 60D}, {"F", 0D}}
```

The above indicates that for "A", points must be at least 90, "B" at least 80, and so on. Note that the list above must be from highest to lowest.

Then to get the grade for a result (point):

```
Dim grade As String = GradeTable.First(Function(g) g.Value <= result).Key
```

where `result` is the decimal value from your formula in the question above.
And `grade` will be either "A", "B", "C", etc.